# I am making a calculator and every time I click a button the whole document turns into that character as if I used document.write(). Why?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```js
var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
var pi = Math.PI;
var power = Math.pow;
var calc, result;

function write(input) {
  var output = document.getElementById('txt');
  output.value = output.value + input
}

function cleer() {
  var output = document.getElementById('txt');
  output.value = '';
}

function equals() {
  var output = document.getElementById('txt');
  calc = output.value;
  result = eval(calc.replace("Not a real number!", "NaN"));
  output.value = result.toString().replace("NaN", "Not a real number!");
}

function factorialize(num) {
  if (num < 0) {
    return -1;
  } else if (num == 0) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return (num * factorialize(num - 1));
  }
}

function square(num) {
  return power(num, 2)
}
var fact = factorialize;
var sq = square;

function onKeyDown() {
  var key = window.event.keyCode;

  // If the user has pressed enter
  if (key == 13) {
    var buttonn = document.getElementById('eq');
    buttonn.click();
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
}

.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-weight: 900;
}

#buttns {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #666;
  width: 325px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#nine {
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 100px;
}

#zero {
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 175px
}

#seven {
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 25px;
}

#eight {
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 175px;
}

#cl {
  background-color: #aaa;
  right: 25px;
  top: 25px;
}

#eq {
  background-color: #aaa;
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 100px;
}

#six {
  bottom: 175px;
  right: 100px;
}

#five {
  bottom: 175px;
  right: 175px;
}

#four {
  bottom: 175px;
  left: 25px;
}

#three {
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 250px;
}

#two {
  right: 175px;
  bottom: 250px;
}

#one {
  left: 25px;
  bottom: 250px;
}

#pl {
  bottom: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

#mi {
  bottom: 100px;
  right: 25px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

#ti {
  bottom: 175px;
  right: 25px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

#di {
  bottom: 250px;
  right: 25px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

#txt {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  font-weight: 900;
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 25px;
}

#po {
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: gray;
}

a:active {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}

p {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<head>

</head>

<body>
  <p><a href="/stuff/#other">«Go back</a></p>
  <h1>
    Calculator
  </h1>
  <div id="buttns">
    <input type="text" id="txt" onkeypress="onKeyDown()">
    <input type="button" value="1" id="one" onclick="write(1)" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="2" id="two" onclick="write(2)" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="3" id="three" onclick="write(3)" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="4" id="four" onclick="write(4)" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="5" id="five" onclick="write(5)" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="6" id="six" onclick="write(6)" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="7" id="seven" onclick="write(7)" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="8" id="eight" onclick="write(8)" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="9" id="nine" onclick="write(9)" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="0" id="zero" onclick="write(0)" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="+" id="pl" onclick="write('+')" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="-" id="mi" onclick="write('-')" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="*" id="ti" onclick="write('*')" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="/" id="di" onclick="write('/')" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="=" id="eq" onclick="equals()" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="C" id="cl" onclick="cleer()" class="buttons">
    <input type="button" value="." id="po" onclick="write('.')" class="buttons">
  </div>
  <h1>
    Instructions
  </h1>
  <p>
    Use 'pi' to use the constant pi.
  </p>
  <p>
    Use 'sqrt(number)' to take square roots.<br>
  </p>
  <p>
    Use 'power(base,exponent)' to raise numbers to a power.<br>
  </p>
  <p>
    Use 'sq(number)' to square numbers.
  </p>
  <p>
    Use 'result' to pull out the last result. This will not work properly if you just loaded the page.
  </p>
  <p>
    To use scientific notation, use for example: '4e+3' for big numbers and '4e-3' for small numbers. These specific ones will return 4000 and 0.004. The numbers can change to anything needed.
  </p>
  <p>
    To find a factorial such as 9!, use fact(integer). If the number is not an integer, it won't work.
  </p>
</body>
```

This does not work and if you click any of the numbers and/or operations the screen just turns white and has that character there in the corner. It seems as if I used `document.write();` but I didn't. I want it to put that charater into the text box (sorry about the size of it) but it does not. Can someone help me? This same code is [here](https://pincescpu987.github.io/stuff/super-calc/). Please ignore the "Go back" link.

Comment: Don't name your function `write()`. The built-in `window.write()` is taking precedence.

Comment: yea, global scope issue.

Comment: Calling `document.write(x)` on a loaded document would essentially open a new page with just `x` in it. You should never use `document.write()` to update document content. use `elem.innerHTML = "new content"` instead.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, I will rename it.